# makefile from Linux doesn't work in OpenSolaris

Tags: linux, build, makefile, opensolaris

In OpenSolaris OS, when I run makefile generated by Eclipse CDT on the Linux OS, I get an error on the first -include line.

The same error was in FreeBSD, and was solved by executing gmake instead of make.
 In OpenSolaris (just installed) gmake doesn't work (command not found).

What package should I install and how exactly, to build Linux-generated C++ project in OpenSolaris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://juliensimon.blogspot.com/2008/12/howto-installing-gmake-gcc-svn-and-git.html) might help you get a working / agreeable tool chain. I'm not sure what you already have, you may just need to install `SUNWgmake` to get up and running. Note, its just the tip of the portability iceberg.

Comment: Thank you, great link. I needed to install both gmake and gcc.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a GNU Make package, you can always download the [source](ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/make/) and build it yourself:

```
tar xjf make-VER.tar.bz2  # or tar xzf for .tar.gz
cd make-VER
./configure
make
make install  # may need to run as root...
```